# Incorrect dupliicate closure by "community"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/108630/11491) about somebody who has been refused a visa once has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216/i-have-been-denied-a-visa-several-times-in-a-row-how-does-one-deal-with-such-se) about dealing with multiple visa refusals. It was closed by "community", whatever that means.

The question is clearly not a duplicate, since it is about a single refusal, not a repeated series of refusals. The one normal user who voted to close the question made a mistaken edit to the title of the post, confusing "failed an exam three times" with "had a visa refused three times". Perhaps that was the basis of the "community" closure, though the edit was corrected before the "community" clese vote.

This question should be reopened.

Also, what does it mean for "community" to vote to close?

Comment: Closed by community means OP agrees it's a duplicate (they are shown a button to accept the close reason).

Comment: Aha -- thanks! I still disagree that it's a duplicate. Even if the asker found the answers to the other question useful, it is a different question.

Comment: If the answers on the target have also answered the new question, yes, it is a duplicate. That doesn't require them to be identical questions, just that answers on one are also answers for the other.

Comment: @Nij On this site, we seem to have adopted the convention that duplicate means "essentially the same question" not "the answers to this other question are also very useful."

Comment: If you believe it should be reopened you may cast a reopen vote. It's up to the community to decide if they agree. I can't reopen it personally as it's not something that requires mod intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Closed by community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930) means that the OP accepted the prompt asking them "is this a duplicate of this other question?":

[image: That solved my problem! / No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how]

If you feel the question was wrongly marked as a duplicate feel free to vote to reopen and explain your reasoning in the comments.